# How long until a bronze tag badge shows up?

Tags: support, tag-badges

If you **check my** [**SO profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176769/karlphillip) you will notice that I finally scored over 100 points on the C tag, and that was a couple of hours ago.

I understand that is the only requirement to earn a **bronze C tag badge**. Am I wrong?

If not, how long do I have to wait to be awarded with the badge?

Thank you.

Comment: Wait a day and come back in the morning

Comment: @random I was just awarded the commentator badge. And that was 2 min after leaving my first 10 comments. Anyway, I think there is space on SO FAQ to inform that not all badges are awarded right away, some requires 24hrs to take effect.

Comment: Just a clarity note, this isn't a concern to you right now but 100 points is *not* the only requirement for a bronze tag badge. You also need at least 20 qualifying answers in that tag, and the tag must be on at least 100 questions. Now, you have 70 qualifying answers and C... has well over 100 questions. But this is just to correct the actual requirements. It still has no impact on the time, which as said may take 24 hours.

Comment: @Grace Thank you very much, mister.

Comment: @random I got it now, thanks. 24hrs is the magic number indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I typically give the StackExchange sites about 24 hours of leeway time before I start worrying about badges, scores, and flair.  It seems like those things are batch processed daily, if not sooner.

Comment: Nobody mentioned StackExchange (so far). But thank you anyway.

Comment: When I say StackExchange, I mean my accounts on SO, SuperUser, ServerFault, Programmers, Gamers, the betas, etc.  Was just trying to save space.