# Is the timing of badge awards documented?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Some badges are awarded instantly (like the early badge awards designed to inspire a pavlovian reaction), some seem to be awarded in some kind of late night batch job (the harder to reach ones?) - is there any way of telling which is which?

So that if you are due a badge, there is a visual clue to suggest how long you should wait before yelling "where's my ^*&%&*%$(& badge!".

Perhaps a little icon with the letter 'i' in it, next to the instantly awarded badges along with a textual note at the bottom of the badges page would be enough.

**ADDENDUM**
As noted below there appears to be a third badge timing, certainly for the 'Tenacious' badge.

Answer (score 2):

"Badges? We don't need no stinkin' badges!" Sorry... could not resist. Sleep deprivation!

I get the idea that some of the badges happen at a certain time due to potentially involved calculations/queries going into earning them. For others, I suspect there is a delay to make sure the trigger event 'sticks'.

But then some easy ones, like your first comment, first vote, etc; as you note, it's very useful to have them appear 'instantly', and those happen to be ones that I would guess are easier to reward quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I recently asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72816/how-long-until-a-bronze-tag-badge-shows-up).

Right now the official answer seems to be **wait 24hrs**.

Comment: Except for Unsung Hero and Tenacious which I think is wait a week