# Why have I not yet received my bronze tag badge?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why doesn't this guy have the Gold Delphi badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98733/why-doesnt-this-guy-have-the-gold-delphi-badge)
>   [Strange tag-badge behavior for scala tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71904/strange-tag-badge-behavior-for-scala-tag)

This question is similar to [another one I found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72816/how-long-until-a-bronze-tag-badge-shows-up), but not identical.  His problem was solved by waiting 24 hours.  I, however, have waited almost 36 hours without a trace of the system's recognition of the fact that I have had 26 posts and 101 votes in a certain tag, for 36 hours now.  [Here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/drm65) my profile.  Can anyone clue me in here?

Comment: Which...tag badge were you hoping for?

Comment: If you look at [my ELU profile](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/drm65), in the tags section, you'll see that I have a single tag [tag:word-choice] with 101 votes and 26 posts.

Comment: And why not ask this on the English.SE Meta site?

Comment: Because it's not an English.SE-specific problem.  It is a technical problem.

Comment: It's explained quite well in my answer. Not sure what you still have a question about. The duplicate question covers the *exact* same problem, you just have to do a little bit of thinking. For example, we're not talking about the Delphi tag and we're not talking about a gold tag badge.

Comment: No, no I understand your saying it was a dupe now.   I didn't see the "Legend" sidebar on the tag badge page, that's all.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Cody: I also didn't know that the counter did not count question-votes.  If I had known that, I wouldn't be posting here.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you were expecting to be awarded the tag badge for [`[word-choice]`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), but you don't meet the requirements yet.

The "Legend" sidebar on the [badges page](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) explains the requirements for each level of tag badge:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

But if I hover over your score for the `[word-choice]` tag in your profile, it says:

> Asked 8 non-wiki questions with a total score of 32. Answered 18 non-wiki questions with a total score of 102.

So you haven't answered enough questions yet. You've only answered 18; you need to answer a minimum of 20 to qualify for the badge.

Answer (score 2):

While you have 102 upvotes in the tag `[word-choice]` you've only answered 18 non-CW questions.

You need to answer at least 20 questions as it states on the tag badge page.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it right now.

Comment: This is the question I was thinking of - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71904/strange-tag-badge-behavior-for-scala-tag